# SQL query asked in interview

Tags: sql, database

A table named fruit has the attributes "ID", "Fruit name" and "Basket No":

```
  |ID | Fruit Name | Basket No|
  |1  |Apple       |1         |
  |2  |Banana      |2         | 
  |3  |Orange      |1         |
  |1  |Apple       |2         |
  |2  |Banana      |3         |
  |3  |Orange      |2         |
  |4  |Mango       |2         |
  |5  |Grapes      |1         |
  |1  |Apple       |3         |
```

I was not able to answer these question.
Can someone help me with following questions:

> **question 1**: Find the basket number which have more than 2 fruits.
>   
>    **question 2**: Find the basket number which contain orange.
>   **question 3**: Find the fruits which are present in more than one basket.
>   I dont know why people are down voting and closing these question.

Comment: why don't you try it yourself first and then ask the question here if you get stuck.

Comment: i Tried but dont know how to do it thats why i asked :)

Comment: Please check: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/, http://www.sql-tutorial.net/ and etc

Comment: Question 2 - SELECT Basket No FROM myTable WHERE Fruit Name = 'Orange'

Comment: @d.danailov please refrain from referencing w3schools. [here's why](http://www.w3fools.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

question 1:find the basket number which have more than 2 fruits.

```
SELECT   basket_no
FROM     baskets
GROUP BY basket_no
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2
```

question 2:find the basket number which contain orange.

```
SELECT DISTINCT basket_no
FROM   baskets
WHERE  fruit_name = 'Orange'
```

question 3:Find the fruits which are present in more than one basket.

```
SELECT   fruit_name
FROM     baskets
GROUP BY fruit_name
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Why does question #2 need LIKE? Based on the info provided and common  knowledge about fruits one can safely omit the "LIKE"

Comment: It should be "fruit_name like 'Orange'" and not "fruit_name like = 'Orange'" if at all you have to use like.

Comment: We need like, because we have "contains" for requirement - "question 2:find the basket number which contain orange."

Comment: @d.danailov...based on the structure of OP's table above I think this is a stretch...each row has one fruit....multiple fruits per basket would be signified by multiple rows based on what OP showed us

Comment: Using like without wildcard is in *most* cases pointless

Comment: Like is not working in second question.
for second question we can do it by
SELECT DISTINCT basket_no
FROM   baskets
WHERE  fruit_name = 'Orange'

Comment: Fixed the second query - the `like` was a mistake caused by a momentary lapse of concentration.

Answer (score 0):

While @Mureinik's answer is correct and should be the accepted answer I propose the following extension to Question 3 (which seems designed to catch the unaware out):

question 3: Find the fruits which are present in **more than one** basket.

For example if there are two Mangoes in basket 2, Mangoes do not meet this requirement and should not be given in the result. I have the following code to take this into account:

```
select  Name
from
(
select  BasketId, 
        Name, 
        count(id) [Fruit Of This Type Per Basket]
from    Fruit
group by BasketId, Name
) as    SubQuery
group by Name
having count(1) > 1
```

This is sql server sql, not sure how standards compliant the subquery is?